# Custom type enforcing for Go structs (type any)

Tags: go, type-conversion

I have a question regarding custom types in Go. I'm trying to get some sort of type safety with `any`. I know union types from TypeScript but as far as I know, union types are not possible in Go. What are viable alternatives?

I want a function or field to have type `any` because I don't know the type upfront. But I also want to limit possible types so that the compiler complains for unexpected ones.

From what I know, this does work with regular custom types like `type x string`, etc. but not with `struct`.

Here is an example with configs:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

type plantConfig any

type treeConfig struct {
    trunkDiameter float64
}

func newTreeConfig(config treeConfig) plantConfig {
    return config
}

type flowerConfig struct {
    color string
}

func newFlowerConfig(config flowerConfig) plantConfig {
    return config
}

// newGarden should only take plantConfig.
func newGarden(config plantConfig) {
    switch config.(type) {
    case treeConfig:
        fmt.Println("planted trees")
    case flowerConfig:
        fmt.Println("planted flowers")
    default:
        fmt.Println("unknown plant")
    }
}

// waterfallConfig is NOT a plantConfig. newGarden should not accept this as
// parameter.
type waterfallConfig struct {
    height float64
}

func main() {
    // This does not report any errors while compiling.
    newGarden(waterfallConfig{})
}
```

Output:

```
unknown plant
```

However, I'd expect the compiler to complain about `newGarden(waterfallConfig{})` because `waterfallConfig` is not of type `plantConfig` and it should not cast implicitly.
Of course, I could make `plantConfig` an interface with a method name that is rather "unique" but this does not seem clean to me. Any suggestions? Or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I think there's no way to do exactly what you're saying (have a type which matches only 2 concrete types - without doing the interface hack you mentioned). But depending on your final goal, maybe something like the functional option pattern could work in your case? Then you can accept only configs/options which are matching your functional option type.

Comment: @phonaputer Ah, yes. Completely forgot about this pattern. Next time, I'll look into that. For now, I redesigned the configuration to directly take target interface types instead of configurations for creating interface implementations. (Originally, I wanted different configurations to be provided in order to create different types of data generator. Now, I export constructors and take the data generator interface directly)

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track but instead of any (interface{}) you want an interface type that restricts the types you can use. So declare plantConfig like this:

```
type plantConfig interface{ ImplementsPlant() }
```

Then you just need to say that the allowed types implement that interface like this:

```
func (treeConfig) ImplementsPlant() {}

func (flowerConfig) ImplementsPlant() {}
```

Comment: Sorry I did not read your final comment.  You appear to have considered my approach.  However, that is the approach you should take in Go, and I wrote a lot of code that way years ago.  But I haven't written anything like that in years as my designs have become less OO.

Comment: I don't think the design would be "so much" OO. Use-case was to have a data generator interface and different types of data generators that would be constructed based on provided config type. But yes, I changed the approach now to export data generator types and generalize usage in order to directly take the data generator interface. Should be much cleaner now. But thanks for the possible solution!

Answer (score 1):

`waterfallConfig` *is* of type `any`.  The clue is in the name.  :)

Creating a new type based on any just creates a new symbol representing the empty interface, which *all types will match*.

The only way I can see to achieve what you want at compile time is to identify some function that all `PlantConfig` types will implement and have `newGarden` accept only `PlantConfig` interfaces.

But as interfaces in Go are duck-typed, rather than formal types, the method(s) of any `PlantConfig` interface will need to be distinct from any methods that your `waterfallConfig` might also implement.

You could even use this to simplify other aspects of your code.

Perhaps something like:

```golang
type PlantConfig interface {
   func PlantType() string
}

type LandscapeFeatureConfig interface {
   func FeatureType() string
}

// treeConfig implements PlantConfig
type treeConfig struct {}

func (treeConfig) PlantType() string { return "tree" }


// flowerConfig implements PlantConfig
type flowerConfig struct {}

func (flowerConfig) PlantType() string { return "flower" }


// waterfallConfig implements LandscapeFeatureConfig
type waterfallConfig struct {}

func (waterfallConfig) FeatureType() string { return "waterfall" }



func newGarden(cfg PlantConfig) {
   fmt.Printf("planted %s\n", cfg.PlantType())
}
```

I have imagined that a waterfall is some other configuration type that you may wish to differentiate, calling it a 'Landscape Feature'; a corresponding `LandscapeFeatureConfig` interface identifies this.  This may or may not be suitable in your case, but it is intended as an illustration only.

With that approach, this code will now not compile:

```golang
func main() {
    // newGarden will only accept PlantConfig
    newGarden(waterfallConfig{})
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. See the comment on solution below how I changed my approach in order to make it more clean. And regarding `any`: Originally, I thought that as with `string` and custom string types, the compiler would not treat them the same.